# Unity 2D - Enemy Ai not jumping when there is ground

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I need some help to see why the ememy wont chase the player when the player jumps up on the ground above.

First let me give the basics of the setup:

**Scene:**

1. I'm using a tilemap
2. It has a tilemap collider 2D
3. it has a static Rigidbody 2D
4. Has a composite Collider 2D
5. Has a Platform Effector 2D
6. It has a layermask set to 'Ground'

**Ememy**

1. Has a Tag called 'Trap'
2. Has a box collider 2D
3. Has a Rigidbody 2D with 'z' roattion freeze enabled

**The Script**

This is the script I have for it:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkSpeed = 4f;
    public float chaseSpeed = 6f;
    public float detectionDistance = 10f;
    public float maxWalkDistance = 10f; 
    public float jumpForce = 10f;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
    private Vector2 initialPosition;
    private bool shouldFlip = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        initialPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);

        if (distanceToPlayer <= detectionDistance)
        {
            // Chase the player
            ChasePlayer();
        }
        else
        {
            // Walk left and right within a set distance
            WalkLeftAndRight();
        }
    }

    private void WalkLeftAndRight()
    {
        // Calculate the movement direction
        Vector2 movement = isFacingRight ? Vector2.right : Vector2.left;

        // Check if the enemy has reached the maximum walking distance
        float currentDistance = Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - initialPosition.x);

        if (currentDistance >= maxWalkDistance)
        {
            shouldFlip = !shouldFlip; // Toggle the flip flag
            initialPosition = transform.position; // Reset initial position
        }

        // Check for ground detection in front of the enemy
        Vector2 groundCheckPosition = transform.position + (isFacingRight ? Vector3.right : Vector3.left) * 0.2f;
        bool isGroundAhead = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheckPosition, Vector2.down, 0.2f, groundLayer);

        // Move the enemy
        if (isGroundAhead)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(movement.x * walkSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else
        {
            shouldFlip = !shouldFlip; // Reverse direction if no ground ahead
        }

        // Flip the sprite if needed
        if (shouldFlip)
        {
            FlipSprite();
        }

        // Check for obstacles above the enemy
        Vector2 obstacleCheckPosition = transform.position + Vector3.up * 0.5f; // Adjust the height as needed
        bool hasObstacleAbove = Physics2D.Raycast(obstacleCheckPosition, Vector2.up, 1f, groundLayer);

        // Check for obstacles and jump if necessary
        Vector2 obstacleAheadCheckPosition = transform.position + (isFacingRight ? Vector3.right : Vector3.left) * 0.2f;
        bool hasObstacle = Physics2D.Raycast(obstacleAheadCheckPosition, movement, 0.2f, groundLayer);

        if (hasObstacle && IsGrounded() && !hasObstacleAbove)
        {
            // Jump to overcome the obstacle
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void ChasePlayer()
    {
        // Calculate the direction to the player
        Vector2 directionToPlayer = (player.position - transform.position).normalized;

        // Move the enemy towards the player
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(directionToPlayer.x * chaseSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        // Flip the sprite if needed
        if ((directionToPlayer.x > 0 && !isFacingRight) || (directionToPlayer.x < 0 && isFacingRight))
        {
            FlipSprite();
        }

        // Jump if the player is on a higher platform
        if (IsPlayerAbove() && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void FlipSprite()
    {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        spriteRenderer.flipX = !isFacingRight;
    }

    private bool IsPlayerAbove()
    {
        // Check if the player is directly above the enemy
        float xOffset = 0.2f; 
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + Vector3.up * xOffset, Vector2.up, 1f, groundLayer);
        return hit.collider != null;
    }

    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        // Check if the enemy is grounded
        float yOffset = 0.1f; 
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position - Vector3.up * yOffset, Vector2.down, 1f, groundLayer);
        return hit.collider != null;
    }
}
```

**The Issue**
When the ememy hits the ground front of it that the player jumped on, it will not jump up as well and chase the player

[image: Stuck on Ground Layer, won't jump up]

Comment: I would guess that `RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position + Vector3.up * xOffset, Vector2.up, 1f, groundLayer);` is nefver hitting what you think.

Comment: @BugFinder is there a easy way to check, I tried adding a debug and you are right, the debug doesnt print anything

Comment: well, personally id probably be lazy and go if i am in front of ground, and player is above me, he got there, so i must jump to join him